# PHP classes are keeping me from accessing the needed variable

Tags: php

ok so i have a php file that includes code for do a sql insert

myfile.php

```
include($somewhere.'/addleads.php');
```

addleads.php

```
require_once(MAIN_CLASS_PATH."common/class.Common.php");
require_once(MAIN_CLASS_PATH."modules/Leads/class.Leads.php");
$objcommon    = new common();
$objLeads     = new Leads();
$Errormsg = $objLeads->AddLBCleads($_REQUEST);
```

class.Leads.php

```
class Leads extends Common{

function Leads(){
    $this->Common();
    $this->Leadstype        = "Leadstype";
    $this->Leads            = "Leads";


}

function AddLBCleads($objArray){

    global $_REQUEST,$objSmarty,$global_config;
    $objLeads = new Leads();
    $objInsertArray['txtP_Ident']       = $objArray['selProperty'];
    $objInsertArray['txtFirstName']     = $objArray['txtfirstname'];
    $objInsertArray['txtLastName']      = $objArray['txtlastname'];
    $objInsertArray['txtEmail']         = $objArray['txtEmail'];
    $objInsertArray['txtPhone']         = $objArray['txtPhone'];
    $objInsertArray['txtTypeId']        = $objArray['selleadtype'];
    $objInsertArray['txtComments']      = $objArray['txtcomments']; 
    $StrEnterdate                       = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $objInsertArray['txtMoveDate']      = $StrMoveDate;
    $objInsertArray['txtEntereddate']   = $StrEnterdate;

    $current_id = $this->AddInfoToDB($objInsertArray,"txt",$this->LBCPrimary_leads);
```

How do i get $current_id from myfile.php, when i try to access it is unavailable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just below this line:

```
class Leads extends Common{
```

Add:

```
public $current_id = null; // create a public accessible variable
```

And instead of:

```
$current_id = $this->AddInfoToDB($objInsertArray,"txt",$this->LBCPrimary_leads);
```

Use:

```
$this->current_id = $this->AddInfoToDB($objInsertArray,"txt",$this->LBCPrimary_leads);
```

Now you can get it like:

```
$objLeads = new Leads();
echo $objLeads->current_id;
```